# Cleaner function overloading without replicating parts that do not change

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type Foo = {
    (trx: Transaction | undefined, event: SomeEnum.OPT_1, params: { whatever: number }): Promise<void>;
    (trx: Transaction | undefined, event: SomeEnum.OPT_2, params: { whatever: string }): Promise<void>;
};

export const foo: Foo = async (trx: Transaction | undefined, event: SomeEnum, params: object | undefined) => {};
```

I'm experimenting with function overloading, the above code works but in my real world case I will have something like 40 overloads where only some of the parameters will be different, so I was wondering, is there a way to improve the code so I don't have to replicate all the invariant elements over and over? In the example, the first parameter `trx` will always be the same, also the return type of the function will always be the same. I tried somethig like this but typescript clearly doesn't like it:

```
type FooPartial<T1 extends SomeEnum, T2> = (trx: Transaction | undefined, event: T1, params: T2) => Promise<void>;

type Foo {
    FooPartial<SomeEnum.OPT_1, { whatever: number }>
    FooPartial<SomeEnum.OPT_2, { whatever: string }>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make dynamic overloading.

In order to do it , you need:

1. compute each overloading in the loop

```js
type Transaction = {
    tag: 'Transaction'
}

type Maps = {
    [SomeEnum.OPT_1]: string;
    [SomeEnum.OPT_2]: number
}


type Overloading = {
    [Ev in keyof Maps]:  (trx: Transaction | undefined, event: Ev, params: Maps[Ev]) => Promise<void>
}
```

2. Now we should get only values of `Overloading` type

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Overloading = Values<{
    [Ev in keyof Maps]:  (trx: Transaction | undefined, event: Ev, params: Maps[Ev]) => Promise<void>
}>
```

3. Now, when we have union of all allowed functions, we need to convert this union to overloaded function. In order to do it you just need use an intersection `&`.

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type Overloading =UnionToIntersection<Values<{
    [Ev in keyof Maps]:  (trx: Transaction | undefined, event: Ev, params: Maps[Ev]) => Promise<void>
}>>
```

Full code

```js
enum SomeEnum {
    OPT_1 = '1',
    OPT_2 = '2'
}

type Transaction = {
    tag: 'Transaction'
}

type Maps = {
    [SomeEnum.OPT_1]: string;
    [SomeEnum.OPT_2]: number
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]


// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type Overloading =UnionToIntersection<Values<{
    [Ev in keyof Maps]:  (trx: Transaction | undefined, event: Ev, params: Maps[Ev]) => Promise<void>
}>>

export const foo: Overloading = async (trx: Transaction | undefined, event: SomeEnum, params: Values<Maps>) => { };

foo({tag:'Transaction'}, SomeEnum.OPT_1, 'string') // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDCmDsFcFsAIGUD21QFEpwN7Fr2B5ABQBUB9ARlgF5YByc2gGhzyLICZq73bgBfEABcAngAdQsYgCcAhuADOMgMaCAlonBdseWIJkBzAFx1pcxSvXheA4CPGwAsjNHytLXAG0kKdDAB0bBQAusbyglKq4PoA3O6wXshoGAEkpOwhsBgARqBS-EJiEgBqMgA2kKDyADzEAHxcxB4A1qDCiABmkkEgwAD0vbBKUqAAJqqCrvqIlbqIsAAWgoIuhv1hyk2IAG657aWIAO5%20Ssi9Mr0ArAAMAMwA7BfsABwAbLaFsACq4JbEiACS4EEuXkoAsGiqn3qNAAFJ9YKAAB7A8AjVxyYSwAD8sBhTWMnwAlNR6ltEKoRrBjOBQDspMSkSi0biWPjYJF2rlYP9gMSqKTySMWDiebhqbTcrF3vZ8HT9jIxlFqN9fgCgSCwWoISVypUqto8B5UFt2ZoWm1Ok4XBlceFEcZTAplFrNAAfWCQVGgdqRUaMBE7IHGY3%200QyWTQeTGK3yI1bIJ8%20qEKTIVSgqpkim1fi1bNgRGiRBSQSDDRhWDtRCIYyy3LyxX6LgyeTCcBKW1Se2SWRO8Fuj1en00kb%20iVBhCJXzQUPhmSR4w6irVGO1ROwTCwPhSyuIGGYPRGWiO8wu2h8f3eJL%20QLkf20MIRKK0Yn9WCIJrAHd7g%20GI89k%20WGeF6TskN7%20gALOwL4DEi4gqKMCJSCmUhAA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe), in my blog, you can find similar solution

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted. I'm new to typescript and I'm amazed by how it can quickly pass from "easy" to "WTF".

Comment: @flagg19 I understand you.It quite unreadable :D